# How to find out call and sms details for last 10 days from my app

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in that I have to fetch all call and sms records for last 10 days. Now I'm only able to find out all contacts for those who has sent me sms and all the phone contacts. So guys please help me show how I can find out or fetch last 10 days call and sms details from my applications?

My code is like this:

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read", null, null);
int readMessagesCount = c.getCount();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Read massage info"+readMessagesCount, 2000).show();
c.deactivate();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String asd = new String(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("address"))); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), asd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the call logs you can use following code: It returns a date by comapring date with current date, you can filter logs of last 10 days.

```
 Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                                   android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null, null, null,
                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
                                int numberColumn = c.getColumnIndex(
                                            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
                                int dateColumn = c.getColumnIndex(
                                            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);

                            // type can be: Incoming, Outgoing or Missed

                                int typeColumn = c.getColumnIndex(
                                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
                                int DurationColumn = c.getColumnIndex(

                                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

                                                            if(c.moveToPosition(0)) 
                                { 
                                    String callerPhoneNumber = c.getString(numberColumn);
                                    String callerPhoneDate = c.getString(dateColumn);
                                    String TYeor = c.getString(typeColumn);



                                String Duration = c.getString(DurationColumn);
                 }
```

And I  think that sms log will also returns date so you can use same logic with sms logs.

Comment: where can i mention number of days to get records..??

Comment: @bindal Hi I type a message from android messaging application and send to you.I write a app and retrieve your number from my code.how can is this possible?could you please help me from this.please mail me mmaidul.islam@gmail.com